# TabView missing in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using `MFMailComposeViewController` to send emails, and the [screen looks like this](http://edumobile.org/iphone/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/o_p-mailsend.jpg)

I have a `TabViewController` in my view, so now when the `MFMailComposeViewController` pops out the `TabView` cann't be seen. What should i do to get the `TabView` bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the default behavior of MFMailComposeViewController. It normally comes in full screen mode only and you cannot set any frame for that. Ideally it is always presented as a model view controller which covers everything which is on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The mail composer interface is not customizable. See the MFMailComposeViewController class reference. You can try to change the frame size, but it will be ignored.

Comment: Ignored means rejected by Apple ?

Comment: I still haven't managed to complete my app, so I haven't got any rejects. :-)

Comment: No, it means that the controller just will not change the size on screen.